# How to rename a menu tab under WooCommerce tab on WordPress admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, hook-woocommerce

I need help in renaming a tab menu item under woocommerce tab on wordpress admin. We installed a plugin that appears as a submenu on woocommerce tab. Can anyone please help me on this?

I found this code below to rename a tab menu, but I dont know what is the tabmenu key of it. Or anyone here how to check tab menu key on my current tab menu items?

```php
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_change_admin_label', 99);
function custom_change_admin_label() {
    global $menu;
    //global $submenu;
    $menu[5][0] = 'Articles';
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The **first part** of the code is to **debug**, this will show you the **menu in detail** on the dashboard. (you can remove this afterwards)

The 2nd part in **this example** changes the **'coupons'** label to **'voucher'**

It is therefore a matter of adjusting based on the detail

```php
// DEBUG: This displays the complete wordpress admin menu on your dashboard for admin only.
function debug_admin_menus() {
    global $menu, $submenu, $pagenow;
    if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
        if( $pagenow == 'index.php' ) {  // print on dashboard
            echo '<pre>', print_r( $menu, 1 ), '</pre>'; // top level menus
            echo '<pre>', print_r( $submenu, 1 ), '</pre>'; // submenus
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'debug_admin_menus' );

// Change label, in this example changes the 'coupons' label to 'voucher'
function custom_change_admin_label() {
    global $menu, $submenu;

    $submenu['woocommerce'][2][0] = 'Voucher'; // rename 'coupons' label
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_change_admin_label' );
```